# AngularJS - How to trigger submit in a nested form

Tags: forms, angularjs

I'm building a form that generates an invitation when submitted.  The invitation has several fields, one of which is an email address input with an 'add' button, which when clicked should add that address to a list of email addresses that should receive the invite.

This can be done with a single form, however if the user hits the enter key while typing an email then it triggers `submit` on the whole form.  I'd like to have the enter key result - when the email input field is focused - have the same effect as clicking the 'add' button.  I expected that the proper way to solve this would be to nest an email entry form within the invitation form, something like this:

```
    <ng-form ng-submit="sendInvite()">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="invitation.title"/>

        <ng-form ng-submit="addInvitee()">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Title" ng-model="inviteeEmail"/>
            <button class="btn" type="submit">add</button>
        </ng-form>

        <button class="btn" type="submit">Send</button>
    </ng-form>
```

With the following javascript in the controller:

```
    $scope.addInvitee = function() {
        $scope.invitation.emails.push($scope.inviteeEmail);
        $scope.inviteeEmail = '';
    }

    $scope.sendInvite = function() {
        //code to send out the invitation
    }
```

My problem is that having nested the forms (and in doing so converted from `<form>` to `<ng-form>`, submitting either one no longer works.

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/q1hfoVajxe0Zr0ChaYOk?p=preview)

Comment: validate form and or provide a prompt ..."You are submitting ...." with a chance to cancel if they aren't done

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly a way to mitigate the issue but it's not ideal behavior.

Comment: could also prevent `enter` default when field in focus. Bind key handler to field and unbind on blur. Can't nest forms

Comment: A key handler might be the way to go.  But what makes you say "can't nest forms"?  [`ngForm`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngForm) was created specifically for that purpose.

Comment: my bad... was unaware of nesting capabilites of `ng-form`. New concept in html

Comment: ng-form has a trap, it doesn't handle ng-submit. source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2513

Answer (score 8):

> You can use one of the following two ways to specify what javascript method should be called when a form is submitted:
>     * ngSubmit directive on the form element
>     * ngClick directive on the first button or input field of type submit (input[type=submit])
>   
> -- [form docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form)

```
<ng-form>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="invitation.title"><br>
   <ng-form>
     <input type="email" placeholder="Title" ng-model="inviteeEmail">
     <button class="btn" ng-click="addInvitee()">add</button><br>
   </ng-form>
   <ul class="unstyled">
     <li ng-repeat="invitee in invitation.invitees">
        <span>{{invitee.email}}</span>
     </li>
   </ul>
   <button class="btn" ng-click="sendInvite()">Send</button>
</ng-form>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SUNNQRevaKYPM4s8LGVe?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, this is an improvement from what I had but it doesn't respond to the `enter` key event at all.  After some fiddling, it would appear that `<form>` and `<ng-form>` elements aren't as identical as the docs claim.  I [forked](http://plnkr.co/edit/mssWTbMyZCTtKuq5tYDJ?p=preview) your Plunker to experiment with different `form`, `ng-form` and `ng-submit` configurations to no avail.  Do you have an idea of how I could get the conditional response to the `enter` key event that I described originally?  (Other than a key handler or custom directive)

Comment: @JamieA, sorry I missed the part about the enter key (I pulled up your Plunker and modified it, but I only tested clicking the buttons).  I think you'll need to create a directive to get the functionality you want.

Comment: The inner submit is doing nothing here. It works due to the ng-click. Angular doesn't seem to want to work with submits on inner forms. A properly working submit can take advantage of ng-submit. The inner submit can not.

Comment: I wanna down vote this answer but i don't have enough points, like Marc said submit isn't doing anything it only works because of the ng-click.

Comment: I edited the answer and removed the `type="submit"` attributes from the two button elements.

Answer (score 8):

I've similar requirement - wizard driven multi-step form. When user clicks 'Next' button, I've to validate the current step form.

We can trigger validation by firing '`$validate`' event on the `scope` bound to the form.

```
isFormValid = function($scope, ngForm) {
    $scope.$broadcast('$validate');
    if(! ngForm.$invalid) {
      return true;
    }
}
```

When ever I want to check if the form values are correct, I'll call `isFormValid` with the scope & form instance.

Working code: [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/oC9TcJySBpbjQQsplJ3c?p=preview)

It is also useful to have few additional logic in `isFormValid` *(included in the above Plunker)* which makes the form & form fields `$dirty` as we would be showing/hiding validation messages based on their `$dirty` state.

Comment: Based on the plunker code I would recommend also toggling the `$pristine` state as it doesn't automatically shift when you set the `$dirty` field. Good work, thanks for the solution!

Comment: At the time of writing (AngularJS < 1.2), doesn't have an easy way to reset the `$pritine` state. We could reset the `$pristine` state of a particular control, or a form. But we also need to propagate that change if any of the other controls in it's form or it's parent form are also `$pristine`. This involves much more. From 1.2, there is a method for that: `$setPristine(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

When the form is submitted, you can find all nested forms using some thing like below

```
forms = []
forms.push(form)
nestedForms = _.filter(_.values(form), (input) -> (input instanceof form.constructor) and (input not in forms))
```

Here, *form* is the outer form controller which was submitted. You can hook this code on ur onsubmit, and find all nested forms and do whatever you have to.

Note: This is coffeescript