# Submitting a form from an external controller button for validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

If you look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HCeHF/1/)

I'm not sure why the internal 'Submit' button triggers browser validation (as per the `required` attribute) but the 'External Button' doesn't?

The external button calls the form `submit()` function so I would expect the same behaviour, no?

I know this probably isn't an Angular problem but I'm looking for an Angular solution that means I don't have to use $element (as I understand this is bad practice).

Comment: The internal submit button triggers `required` behavior because its a browser default behavior. You cannot trigger the `required` behavior by submitting a form using javascript. You have to find some other way to show users what they should do with the form. You might want to use the `$valid` property that comes with `ngForm`.

Comment: Thanks. If you add this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal submit button triggers required behavior because its a browser default behavior. You cannot trigger the `required` behavior by submitting a form using javascript. You have to find some other way to show users what they should do with the form. You might want to use the `$valid` property that comes with `ngForm`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use $element, you trigger events in pure javascript, and angular does not know what's going on so it can't, in this case, validate the form. You should trigger the form validation first :

```
$scope.$broadcast('$validate');
if(!ngForm.$invalid)
   $element.find("form")[0].submit();
```

For this to work, please define your form with the ng-form tag, like this:

```
<ng-form> /* BLABLABLA */ </ng-form>
```

More info here:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngForm

You can also check this:

[AngularJS - How to trigger submit in a nested form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937294/angularjs-how-to-trigger-submit-in-a-nested-form/17082917#17082917)

Comment: Thanks. The validation I was looking for was browser inbuilt validation however.