# Trigger ng-submit on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816757/how-to-manually-trigger-a-forms-submit-in-angularjs#11837152) answer (and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/unWF3/6/) fiddle) on how to accomplish this.

**View:**

```
<section>
    <form style="display: none" id="addFriendForm" name="vm.form.addFriendForm" class="form-horizontal" submit-on="submitAddFriendForm" ng-submit="vm.save(vm.form.addFriendForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        <input ng-model="vm.userInput" required>
    </form>
    <div class="list-group">
        <a ng-repeat="user in vm.users" ng-click="vm.triggerSubmit(user)" class="list-group-item">
            ...
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Directive:**

```
function submitOn() {
    return {
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on(attrs.submitOn, function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Error:
                    element.trigger('submit');
                });
            });
        }
    };
}
```

**Controller:** *(`triggerSubmit`)*

```
// Trigger submit of the form
function triggerSubmit(user) {
    vm.userInput = user;
    $scope.$broadcast('submitAddFriendForm');
}
```

When walking through this, I get the error:

> TypeError: element.trigger is not a function

...on the line highlighted in the directive. Looking at docs, this seems correct. What's the reason for it failing?

**ANSWER:**
*(if a jQuery answer is wanted, look at the answer below)*

A pure angular way of doing it is:

```
angular.element(element).triggerHandler('submit');
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `trigger` is not a part of JQLite which ships with angular.
You might have to load JQuery before loading angular.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>`

OR

As part of your build pipeline (grunt/gulp/webpack etc)

Comment: Thank you! I feel like this will have worked but instead I found an angular way of doing it

Comment: Ah nice. That's even better then. Care to tell us how?

Answer (score 1):

See the other answer for a jQuery approach. For a pure  angular approach I used:

```
angular.element(element).triggerHandler('submit');
```